# Assign the selected value to a variable

Tags: qliksense

I have a customers Field loaded from a DB server and I have it on my sheet in a Field object or table object. My question is how can I assign the selected customer to a variable?

Thanks in advance.
Ziad.

Comment: Please can you provide more detail as to what you are trying to achieve by setting a variable? #

Comment: yep for sure.
I have a list of values which loaded for a DB table, what I need is to choose one of these values and give it back to a variable, as the variable is used in the script in the "where" section (for example:select ......... where Customer= $(vCustomer).

Thanks Chris!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure that what you're after would be the best way of getting the data... variables in Qlik can only hold a single value, not an array - could you pull both tables in fully and link in Sense instead. Or are you trying to only pull through the relevant entries from the second table? it might be worthwhile looking into the exists function if you are.